# How to call / access an Angular method from third party api function? (integrating ApplePay into Angular website)

Tags: angular, typescript, function, applepay

I am a rookie to Angular and here is my question:

I'm trying to integrating Apple Pay into a website by using Angular11.
Now I've been install a npm package which contains type definitions for Apple Pay JS (@types/applepayjs).But now I can't access my function from this api-function.

All of my functions or variables in api-function are becoming "any" type and showing not defined. I have to send data to back-end server to communicate with Apple and get the return message from server. I'm wondering if it’s because of the scope reason or language reason.

Can I call my function from a third party definitions function or access the Dependency Injection service by constructor? If there are any solutions or suggestions?

Please help and Thank you so much.

Here is my code.
component.ts

```
        
    export class ApplepayComponent {
        
        constructior(
            private service: ApplepayService
        ){}

        // ...........
        
        doApplePay(){
            
            const paymentRequest: ApplePayJs.ApplePayPaymentRequest = {
                countryCode: 'US',
                currencyCode: 'USD',
                supportedNetworks: ['visa', 'masterCard'],
                merchantCapabilities: ['supports3DS'],
                total: { label: 'My Store', amount: '10.00' }                
            }

            const session  = new ApplePaySession(2, paymentRequest);
            session.onvalidatemerchant = function(event) {
                const validationURL = event.validationURL;

                // here is my question
                // I want to call my service to communicate with back-end server
                this.service.validateApplePay(this.secretKey).then((result) =>{
                    const merchantValidation = result.DATA.RETURN_MSG;
                    // and if complete, call 
                    session.completeMerchantValidation(result.RETURN_MSG)
                });
                
            }
        }

        
    }
```

service.ts

```
export class ApplepayService {
        constructior(
            private service: ApiService
        ){}
        async validateApplePay(secretKey: string):Promise<any>{
            const res = await this.apiService.valdateApplepay({
                SECRET_KEY: secretKey
            }).toPromise();
            return res;
        }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to run this? On a web browser? or in an app?

Comment: @Apps I try to run it on the web with angular and spring boot.

Comment: I don't think this will work in non iOS or MacOS environments. even if you get the method invocation working

Comment: Yes. I think I should detect the user’s browser first to check availability for Apple Pay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because your context variable `this` is not available inside your `api-function`. Try one of these.

Convert your `function` to a `fat arrow function`.

```
session.onvalidatemerchant = (event) => { ... }
```

or, pass `this` into another variable

```
var self = this;
session.onvalidatemerchant = function(event) {
    self.(...)
}
```

[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: It's a great help to me. I'll try this way. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad to know I could help. More importantly, this is a `JavaScript` question rather than an `Angular` question. I would suggest you to read more on the `this` keyword. You can start here: https://dev.to/vyasriday/what-the-heck-is-this-in-javascript-37n1